# TypeError: stub expected to yield, but no callback was passed returned from unit test

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am trying to write a unit test that should perform an integration test between a REST endpoint and the controller belonging to it. The test should mock the call to the database so no database connection is established during testing.

I am using chai-http to make the HTTP call to the endpoint and sinon with sinon-mongoose to mock the Mongoose models calls.

```
const set = [{ _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 }, { _id: 3 }];

//Require the dev-dependencies
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { describe, it } = require('mocha');
require('sinon-mongoose');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../src/server');

const should = chai.should();

// set up mocks
const MyModel = require('../src/models/myModel');

const MyModelMock = sinon.mock(MyModel);
MyModelMock.expects('find').yields(set);

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('My endpoints', () => {
  describe('/GET to my endpoint', () => {
    it('it should GET all the info I want', (done) => {
      chai.request(server)
        .get('/api/myEndpoint')
        .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Googling this error did not yield any results that I am able to work with. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case someone ever runs into this (most likely future me).

I managed to solve my issue. I was using promises in my code and should have set up my mock accordingly (also chaining correctly).

```
MyModelMock.expects('find').chain('where').chain('in').chain('exec').resolves(set);
```